# verify domain sent email

Tags: php, email

How can I prove to email clients that the sent email was sent from the domain which the email was sent from? I have included the code I use to send emails.

[image]

```
$headers = "From: noreply@mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: noreply@mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";  
$to = $_GET['to'];
$subject = $_GET['subject'];
$message = $_GET['message'];
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: **dkim** and **spf** are your friend

Comment: @nogad thankyou so much will take a look into them and hopefully solve my issue, thanks again. :-)

Comment: spf should be a no-brainer in this day and age, dkim is a nice to have